# ARCORE on 96 hickey board

Tags: arcore

So I want to run ARcore on hickey board, I am currently running Android 9.0 AOSP on it. Is it possible to run an AR application on hickey board with an external USB camera? do I need a specific camera or is there anything else I need in order to run AR applications on hickey board? or hickey even supports the AR core? if you could answer this it would really help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARCore has some minimum system requirements including sensors, cameras etc.

I don't believe there is an official minimum requirements set published openly at this point but there is a list of supported devices: https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

Google actually test and certify these devices so I don't think you will find 'official' support for you set up - they say:

> To certify each device, we check the quality of the camera, motion sensors, and the design architecture to ensure it performs as expected. Also, the device needs to have a powerful enough CPU that integrates with the hardware design to ensure good performance and effective real-time calculations.